# How to transform a data matrix to a data frame with respect to coordinates

Tags: r

I have vectors of coordinates as

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y = c(1, 2, 3)
```

and a matrix of observed values on these locations

```
matrix(round(rnorm(12, 10, 4)), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10    9   11
[2,]   14   11   13
[3,]   15   10    6
[4,]   14   11   17
```

I would like to transform this into a data frame such that

```
x y z
1 1 10
1 2 9
1 3 11
2 1 14
2 2 11
2 3 13
```

I am new to R and tried to deal with loops, but is there any straightforward way of doing this for larger matrixes and coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

An option is to create row/column index with 'x', 'y' using `expand.grid`, use that to extract the elements of matrix ('m1') to create three column data.frame

```
d1 <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y) 
out <- transform(d1, z = m1[as.matrix(d1)])
out[order(out$x), ]
#   x y  z
#1  1 1 10
#5  1 2  9
#9  1 3 11
#2  2 1 14
#6  2 2 11
#10 2 3 13
#3  3 1 15
#7  3 2 10
#11 3 3  6
#4  4 1 14
#8  4 2 11
#12 4 3 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go is transforming your data to a **data.frame**, make some changes and use the pivot_long() function from tidyr. Please notice that this is a new function so is likely that you will have to install the library again.

```
library(tidyr)

x = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y = c(1, 2, 3)

Data <- matrix(round(rnorm(12, 10, 4)), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
Data <- as.data.frame(Data)
names(Data) <- c("1","2","3")
Data$x = c(1,2,3,4)

pivot_longer(Data, c("1","2","3"), names_to = "y", values_to = "z")
```